# reset hover property of css element

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress website and adding some custom javascript and CSS for a particular page. I'm new to CSS and after reading a lot of different entries still can't figure out the answer.

The theme I am using sets the hover property for certain table elements and now I need to *unset* those since it is interfering with the page I am creating. If I remove the theme CSS rule then everything is fine, but the rest of the site doesn't work, plus I don't want to change the parent theme. I can't figure out how to just remove the properties of hover that are already defined. It seems that I should be able to make a more specific rule that does what I want to do, but I can't seem to get that done either. I think this is probably a simple problem but I can't seem to find the answer.

I want to override the all rules that effect the hover characteristics of a table.

```
/* from the theme */
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1.62em 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

td,
th {
  padding: .5em 1em
}

/* this is my problem rule */
tbody tr:hover td,
tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/4ty7h8oy/4/

Comment: Not a great solution but I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4ty7h8oy/7/) is your best bet with CSS.

Comment: It is a brute force way of doing it (it was kind of what I was expecting I would have to do.) Your example shows how it is done though and that is is a great help to me. Thanks @Harry.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

You can add a custom class to your tr or td like this and define css properties to that, and it will not affect other tr to td:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="myclass">
      <td class="lastMonth">1</td>
      <td class="thisMonth">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="today">2</td>
      <td class="nextMonth">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myclass">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tbody tr.myclass:hover td,
  tbody tr.myclass:hover th {
    background-color: rgba(56, 25, 44, .05)
  }
```